# How to use C++11 chrono header for a clock

Tags: game-loop, sfml, c++

In first, sorry for my bad english. :)
I'm making a game using SFML and C++11 new features, but I've got a problem with my custom Clock class (made to replace the SFML one).
When I get the elapsed time since the clock instanciation, it returns it in microseconds. But I'd want it to return nanoseconds, I don't understand what happens.
My question is, why do I get microseconds instead of nanoseconds ?
Here is my main :

```
#include "clock.h"
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800,600), "title");
    sf::Event event;
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    Clock<std::chrono::nanoseconds> clock;

    while(window.isOpen()) {
        while(window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed) window.close();
        }

        std::cout << clock.Restart().count() << std::endl;
        /* I would like it to print about 16666666 (ns), but it prints about 16666 (μs) */

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And there is my Clock.h file :

```
#ifndef CLOCK_H
#define CLOCK_H

#include <chrono>

template < typename Period >
class Clock {
public:
                                                                    Clock();
    Period                                                          GetElapsedTime() const;
    Period                                                          Restart();

private:
    std::chrono::time_point< std::chrono::high_resolution_clock >   mTimePoint;
};

template < typename Period >
Clock< Period >::Clock()
    : mTimePoint( std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() ) {
}

template < typename Period >
Period Clock< Period >::GetElapsedTime() const {
    const Period elapsedTime( std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - mTimePoint );
    // Here, elapsedTime.count() equals ~16666 too, but I want nanoseconds, so why ?!
    return elapsedTime;
}

template < typename Period >
Period Clock< Period >::Restart() {
    const Period period( GetElapsedTime() );
    mTimePoint = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    return period;
}

#endif // CLOCK_H
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to GDSE. You did not really specify the problem. There's no question, in your question. We don't debug code here, use your favorite tool to do that. Reformat your post so, that there's one question, that someone could answer.

Answer (score 3):

First, your code should display time in nanoseconds as you asked. If you want more help on what is displayed, show us the output.

Second:

> My question is, why do I get microseconds instead of nanoseconds ?

If you are on Windows, using Visual Studio 2012 or 2013, there is a bug in the chrono standard library implementation that makes the high resolution clock having around 8 milliseconds resolution instead of something closer to micro or nanoseconds.

> Thanks for reporting this bug. I wanted to let you know what's
>   happening with it. I'm still keeping track of it, but it's been
>   resolved as "Deferred" because we may not have time to fix it in VC12.
>   (Note: VC8 = VS 2005, VC9 = VS 2008, VC10 = VS 2010, VC11 = VS 2012.)

Source: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/719443/#

At the moment, if you want to keep using a cross-platform stl-like library usage, do like me, use Boost.Chrono instead. It works as expected and have a good granularity on Windows and other platforms. Using it, maybe with typedefs or 'using' instructions, makes you use the same interface as chrono but you can still switch to the standard library once you get the fixed implementation. (or use a different C++ implementation)

One important thing to note though: standard library threading facilities for waiting (std::sleep_for/until, std::condition_variable and std::mutex members) are dependant on std::chrono. This means that if you want to use them you will have the same time precision problem using Visual Studio 2012/13 when using these synchronization tools. It might not be a problem for a lot of application, except most games, because slow downs dues to longer waits can easily be perceptible by the player.

So if you decide to use standard threading facilities, and want high precision, use Boost.Thread and Boost.Chrono together. Boost.Chrono can't be used with the standard thread library, so you either have to live with the precision bug or use Boost.Chrono and Boost.Thread together.

I'm sure it will be fixed in coming patches but don't expect such a fix before the beginning of 2014 (or the very end of 2013 but I don't count no it).